# Access class members via enum indexer in compact fashion

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a compact way in C# to implement this construct:

```
public class Test {
    public enum Field {
        A, B, C, D, E...
    }

    public int a = 0;
    public int b = 0;
    public int c = 0;
    public int d = 0;
    public int e = 0; //....

    public int this[Field field] {
        set{
            switch(field) {
                case(Field.A):
                    a = value;
                    break;
                case(Field.B):
                    b = value;
                    break;
                ...
            }
        }

        get{
            switch(field) {
                case(Field.A):
                    return a;
                case(Field.B):
                    return b;
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The class is pretty much a fixed collection of fields that share the same type, have different default parameters, and must be accessed individually (via `.a`) AND through indexer.

This is going to be called a LOT so reflection probably is not an option

In C++, I could make a macro for this kind of thing, but C# doesn't have any.

How can I implement this without writing a wall of repeating text?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: One of the wonderful design features of C# is that it doesn't give you efficient syntax for doing crazy things. You may be interested, however,  in a key value store like a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Use a collection instead of many fields of the same type and similar meaning.

Comment: Your entire class can be replaced with a `Dictionary<Field, int>` also `enum`s already have `int` values, you could just assign the `int` straight to the `enum`

Comment: There is a fast solution for this, but it requires a lot more set-up code than your `switch`, so unless you want to do it in a great deal of different classes, your `switch`-based solution is probably ideal.

Comment: @Andrew Since `enum` values are small consecutive integers, an array of `int`s would work even better.

Comment: You have put the body of your setter into your getter, and vice versa.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Because I've run into situation where I need to apply same algorithm to specific fields only. This approach would eliminate code duplication.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: you know, with 200k rep it should be fairly easy to understand what I meant and realize that I made a typo.

Comment: @Andrew: "Your entire class can be replaced with", no, it can't be replaced, because fields have specific meaning, and that way I'll introduce useless syntaxic sugar.

Comment: @NathanCooper: "it doesn't give you efficient syntax" Which is why I dislike it to this day. I want maximum power, not a babysitter. I know what dictionary is, and outlined why it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: "There is a fast solution for this, but it requires a lot more set-up code" Thanks for the comment. Would be nice to know what that alternative is, even if it is even clumsier. Just drop a comment if you don't feel like writing answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is pretty efficient in terms of CPU use, so it is very hard to beat. If you would like to get some efficiency in terms of syntax, you could switch your design around - store your data in an array for convenience of access through an `enum`, and use properties to provide nice-looking names for external users:

```
public class Test {
    public enum Field {
        A, B, C, D, E..., X, Y, Z
    }
    private readonly int[] data = new int[(int)(Field.Z + 1)];
    public int A {
        get {
            return data[Field.A];
        }
        set {
            data[Field.A] = value;
        }
    }
    //...
    public int Z {
        get {
            return data[Field.Z];
        }
        set {
            data[Field.Z] = value;
        }
    }
    public int this[Field field] {
        set{
            data[field] = value;
        }

        get{
            return data[field];
        }
    }
}
```

This approach has a lot of code repetition. You could avoid it altogether at the price of building a somewhat heavyweight setup code below:

```
class Program {
    public enum Field { A, B, C };
    public int a, b, c;
    private static readonly Func<Program,int>[] Getter= new Func<Program,int>[3];
    private static readonly Action<Program,int>[] Setter= new Action<Program,int>[3];
    public int this[Field f] {
        get {
            return Getter[(int)f](this);
        }
        set {
            Setter[(int) f](this, value);
        }
    }
    static Program() {
        var names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Field));
        var pThis = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Program), "pThis");
        var pVal = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "pVal");
        for (var i = 0 ; i != names.Length ; i++) {
            var f = Expression.Field(pThis, names[i].ToLower());
            Getter[i] = Expression.Lambda<Func<Program, int>>(f, pThis).Compile();
            var a = Expression.Assign(f, pVal);
            Setter[i] = Expression.Lambda<Action<Program,int>>(a, pThis, pVal).Compile();
        }
    }
    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("a={0} b={1} c={2}", a, b, c);
    }
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        var p = new Program();
        p.a = 123;
        p.b = 456;
        p.c = 789;
        Console.WriteLine(p);
        p[Field.A] = 234;
        p[Field.B] = 567;
        p[Field.C] = 890;
        Console.WriteLine(p);
        Console.WriteLine(p[Field.A]);
        Console.WriteLine(p[Field.B]);
        Console.WriteLine(p[Field.C]);
    }
}
```

This approach builds and compiles getters and setters in the static constructor, making sure that the reflection is used only once. Note that this approach relies on convention that lowercased names of `enum` correspond to names of fields. If this is not the case, replace this line

```
Expression.Field(pThis, names[i].ToLower());
```

with some other way of getting the field name out of `enum` name. This code also assumes that `enum` values are consecutive, and start at zero.

Comment: I thought about this solution. Aaand there's no way to shorten this, I take it?